# Should tags with "poker" in the name be allowed?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems silly to me to have "poker" in the tags on a poker site.

We currently have tags for "poker-theory" and "poker-tools".  Should they stay as is, or be changed to "theory" and "tools"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take out the word "poker". If it's not related to that anyway, it doesn't belong on the site.